# Specific Field Wont Display In Mongo DB Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of Book Reviews where I am trying to find users who have created multiple reviews (lets say 5), I also want to return the number of reviews, their unique ID and their Name.

So far I have managed to find a way of doing this through aggregation, however for the life of me I cant seem to return the name field, I assumed a simple $project would be fine but instead I can only see the ID and the Number of reviews someone has made, what am i missing to fix this?

Current Code:

```
db.bookreviews.aggregate([   
    {"$group": {"_id": "$reviewerID","NumberOfReviews": { "$sum": 1 }}}, 
    {"$match": {NumberOfReviews: {"$gte": 5}}},
    {"$project":{_id:1,NumberOfReviews:1, reviewerName:1}},
])
```

Returned Values:

```
    {IDXYZ, NumberofReviews 5},                 
    {IDABC, NumberofReviews 5},                 
    {ID123, NumberofReviews 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$first` to keep the first document of that group and keep the value of `reviewerName` in your `$group` stage and you can remove the `$project`.

```
db.bookreviews.aggregate([   
    {"$group": {"_id": "$reviewerID","NumberOfReviews": { "$sum": 1 }, "reviewerName": { "$first": "$reviewerName" } } }, 
    {"$match": {"NumberOfReviews": {"$gte": 5}}},
])
```